# Error when trying to install listings package in MikTex

Tags: listings, miktex, installing

I'm trying to install the 'listings' package through MiKTeX package manager and I get the following error:

MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: parse error - unexpected end of input; expected '}'
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit, Service Pack 1, build 7601

Comment: When you say "package manager" do you mean you used current MiKTeX-console > packages screen and hit + or are you using an older mpm command ?

Comment: I'm using MiKTeX packge Manager which appears to be the same software that opens when you do windowskey + R -> mpm. I have looked at the question posted. When I try to go on the update wizard and update my packages, I get the same error as above. When I try to synchronize the repository the software crashes.

Comment: I switched repositories like suggested in the other post and that worked. Thank you @KJO!